# Is it possible to set the default iTerm profile using CLI?

Tags: macos, iterm2

I'm trying to write a MacOS provisioning script for iTerm2 which will (1) load in a dynamic profile and (2) set it to use as the default profile.

Loading the profile is just a matter of putting it in the `~/Library/Application\ Support/iTerm2/DynamicProfiles`.  Setting that profile to be the default is a bit more tricky.

I see that the Python API exposes a way to update the default profile, but I was hoping to be able to use the `com.googlecode.iterm2` plist.  I see there is a `Default Bookmark Guid` plist entry, but setting that seems to have no effect.

Has anybody done this?  Again my goal is to have zero user interaction in order to specify the default profile.

Answer (score 0):

iTerm has a Python API that allows you to do this.

Personally, I solved this by creating [this script](https://github.com/jamesdh/dotfiles/blob/8fbe5409c6bb26bce9d50e2328359f5a37edd716/roles/osx/files/iTerm/change_default_profile.py):

```python
import iterm2

async def main(connection):
    all_profiles = await iterm2.PartialProfile.async_query(connection)
    for profile in all_profiles:
        if profile.name == "Projects":
            await profile.async_make_default()
            return

iterm2.run_until_complete(main)
```

Then, [using Ansible](https://github.com/jamesdh/dotfiles/blob/8fbe5409c6bb26bce9d50e2328359f5a37edd716/roles/osx/tasks/per_app/iterm.yml), I link that script into iTerm's [autorun dir](https://iterm2.com/python-api/tutorial/running.html?highlight=run#auto-run-scripts):

```
- name: Link iTerm AutoLaunch Scripts 
  file: 
    src: "{{role_path}}/files/iTerm/change_default_profile.py"
    path: "{{iterm.autorun_dir}}/change_default_profile.py"
    state: link
    force: true
```

Then anytime you startup iTerm, it should default to the profile defined in the startup python script.